# Placing child above and outside overflow parent

Tags: html, css

in the following code example, I'd like to place my circle outside the red div and still be seen. however due to parent's `overflow: auto` it is not fully seen, even when I change `overflow-x` to visible and `overflow-y` to auto. the granchilds overflows but i still see their circles

```css
.parent {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.grand-child {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: hotpink;
    border: black 1px solid;
}

.circle {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: green;
    left: -5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="grand-child">
                <span class="circle">
                    ss
                </span>
                <span>
                    hello
                </span>
                <span>
                    world
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="grand-child">
                <span class="circle">
                    ss
                </span>
                <span>
                    hello
                </span>
                <span>
                    world
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="grand-child">
                <span class="circle">
                    ss
                </span>
                <span>
                    hello
                </span>
                <span>
                    world
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="grand-child">
                <span class="circle">
                    ss
                </span>
                <span>
                    hello
                </span>
                <span>
                    world
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="grand-child">
                <span class="circle">
                    ss
                </span>
                <span>
                    hello
                </span>
                <span>
                    world
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

//  Removing overflow: auto;
//  add position:fixed;

```css
.parent {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.circle
{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: green;
    left:8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <span class="circle">
                ss
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi there, your solution seems to work, however when child's content overflows is still shows the circle though the grandchild is not displayed, check out the updated question

Comment: think of it like "to do" list item